# How to take multiple inputs from console in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i'm fairly new to javascript and i have been trying to find a number in an array and return the index of the number if found, else return -1. This is what i've done

```js
function search(){
    
}
search.prototype.arr = function(){
    const readline = require("readline");
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('enter a list: ',(arr)=>{
        var list = arr.split(' ');
        console.log(list);
        rl.close();
        return list;
        
    });
}

search.prototype.num = function(){
    const readline = require("readline");
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('enter a number: ',(num)=>{
        var number = num;
        rl.close();
        return number;
    });
}

search.prototype.findIndex = function(){
    var list = this.arr();
    var number = this.num();
    var i = 0;
    while (i < list.length){
        if (list[i] == number){
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (i == list.length){
        return -1;
    }
}

var s = new search();
console.log(s.findIndex());
```

and i expected the console to take a list of numbers with white-space separated e.g 2 4 3 6 7 and when i press enter it should take a number and print the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is likely because of the asynchronous functions you are using to read the input. So what happens is that your two functions are returning before the input streams have been read.

So returning promises for all your functions instead will allow those values to be read before continuing onto the next step.

```
function search(){

}
search.prototype.arr = function(){
    const readline = require("readline");
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question('enter a list: ',(arr)=>{
            var list = arr.split(' ');
            console.log(list);
            rl.close();
            resolve(list);

        });

    })
}

search.prototype.num = function(){
    const readline = require("readline");
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rl.question('enter a number: ',(num)=>{
            var number = num;
            rl.close();
            resolve(number);
        });
    });
}

search.prototype.findIndex = async function(){
    var list = await this.arr();
    var number = await this.num();
    var i = 0;
    var idx = -1;
    while (i < list.length){
        if (list[i] == number){
            idx = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return Promise.resolve(idx);
}

var s = new search();

s.findIndex().then((idx) => console.log(idx));
```